# Can multiple render systems be used?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

I was watching a tutorial how to design an island in Blender,
which worked really great, but i didn't want to use the .png Trees the guy used there. So i watched another tutorial and created another kind of tree - without knowing that the object isn't just modeled in Cycles Render, it is also rendered in there.

My problem is either the (lets say "simple" textured) island (rendered in Blender render) or the tree is shown. Is there any way i can "convert" that cycles object (with its shaders) to Blender Render or the other way around? Or just render with two renders in one project? I haven't found something about that til now. If there is no universal solution for that, i could also put a link to my project in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Yes you can combine images created with two different renderer engines. These are optimistic scenarios.

- Different Scenes can have different render Engines. Cycles or Blender Internal.
- The [Compositor] can invoke and combine images from different Scenes.  The Render Layer Node names the scene and Render Layer.  In the nodes above the text [Blender] was rendered Blender Internal Render and the word [Cycles] was rendered with Cycles Render.  Note the transparent background for the Cycles render.
- If your desired result can be composed in visual layers fine.  Only you can determine that.
- Cycles has a different approach to Blender render so only you can determine what compromises you can tolerate for a coarse translation.  Just create a new material for the appropriate render engine and assign it to the faces and judge that result.
- The VSE can also combine images with transparent backgrounds for the layered composition effect.

Comment: Is this also working on animating (doing a video)?

Comment: Yes.  The compositor transforms each frame of a animation.

Comment: So do i have to set all other textures in Cycles to transparent?