# Is it possible to have multiple seperate node editors in one project?

Tags: node-editor

I want to do a project where it is necessary to use multiple green screen videos on top of one normal video, is it possible to have more than 1 node editor per project? I don't want to render my video every 5 minutes so that I could just add another greenscreen video to another part of the base video. (Picture is just for a reference, for example, is it possible to make the right node editor empty and independent of the left node editor?)

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwGAI.jpg

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48099/how-to-build-different-scenarios-in-the-compositor/48110#48110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAAAAnd I figure out how to use scenes to get different node editors in half an hour, what are the odds? (Just add a new scene whenever you want to do different effects in node editor in the same project and then add those scenes to the VSE)