# Is it possible to use different compositor settings for different layers?

Tags: compositing-nodes, layers

I'm trying to render a second layer and every time I change something in the compositor, it makes the same changes for all layers.  Is it possible to have certain settings in the compositor for one layer and different ones for another layer?

Essentially, I am trying to get one object to have a certain colour and effect with the compositor, and the background object to have different settings in the compositor.

In this picture I have the node setup for scene 2, which is the same setup as scene 1.  If I change anything in scene 1, the exact same nodes will show in scene 2.  I want different nodes in the compositor for different scenes.

[image: scene 2]

Thanks

Comment: maybe related... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48099/how-to-build-different-scenarios-in-the-compositor/48110#48110 please [edit] your question and add more information on what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can use different scenes with linked objects but different settings, then pull all renders from different files into the compositor

Comment: Ok I've edited the question to be more precise.  I'm guessing different scenes then would accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by compositor? World material nodes? Or actual post processing nodes? Can you post your node setup? Each renderlayer can only be imported in the compositor as a single layer.

Comment: I mean compositing screen layout for post processing nodes.  The picture I've added is the node setup I don't want for scene 2.  But any time I change or delete any nodes in scene 1, it makes the same changes in scene 2.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out.  I didn't select the right scenes in the Render Layers node.  [image]